# If Last 2 Digits Of Cell Value Are Greater Than And Less Than

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for the following formula.

I have a Named Range "Width" which is always a 3 digit value eg.126,298,300,495 etc.

If the last 2 digits of the value from Named Range "Width" is greater than or equal to 00 and less than or equal to 49 then return "True" else "False"

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(Width,2)>=00,(RIGHT(Width,2)<=49)),"True","False")
```

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that `RIGHT` returns a **string**, which you are then comparing to a **numeric**. Also, it's generally preferable to return **Boolean** `TRUE`/`FALSE` results, rather than **text** entries like "True" and "False". So:

`=AND(0+RIGHT(Width,2)>=0,0+RIGHT(Width,2)<=49)`

FYI you could also consider the simpler:

`=ISEVEN(QUOTIENT(Width,50))`